# Configuring dnsmasq in Mint/Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: linux-mint, networkmanager, dnsmasq

I have a computer with multiple ethernet ports - one goes out to the internet, the rest connects to other devices to give them internet connectivity. The DHCP service is provided by dnsmasq. The computer also has a couple samba shares that are shared with the "internal" interfaces only. I thought this was all a pretty vanilla setup.

In Mint 18, all this simply worked without disruption.

Updating to Mint 18.1 introduced some weirdness in NetworkManager, where dnsmasq comes up like this:

`ps -ef | grep dnsm
nobody    5099  5080  0 16:55 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`

The problem is the part that says "--conf-file=/dev/null" as this seems to prevent dsnmasq from actually reading the configuration file in /etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d

I can 'systemctl stop NetworkManager' followed by a 'killall -9 dnsmasq' and then re-issue the dnsmasq "by hand" - but that's extremely ugly at best (and costs me all the other NetworkManager functionality).

Sifting through all the various files in /etc/NetworkManager and /usr/lib/NetworkManager and such I cannot find the place where 'conf-file=/dev/null' is specified, so I'm guessing it's a default that needs to be overridden somewhere/somehow but I don't know how or where - "man NetworkManager.conf" isn't really helping.

Answer (score 2):

NM passes the conf-file to prevent dnsmasq to load the default configuration file.

Note however:

```
--conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Comment: Yes, it sets that conf dir. It just never *reads* anything in the directory because of the "conf-file=/dev/null" part. I do have the correct configuration in that directory - and as a matter of fact if I kill NM and then start dnsmasq by hand it finds it and reads it just fine and works as it's supposed to. It's just not working when started from NM because NM insists on that stupid /dev/null thing and I don't know where to override that...

Answer (score 2):

As above, it is apparent that the problem is caused by the `--conf-file (blank) directive` being issued by `NetworkManager` when it starts `dnsmasq` . How can I remove this directive from the command line that `NetworkManager` is issuing? Apparently a test that `NetworkManager` is performing is not working properly:

```
strings /usr/sbin/NetworkManager|grep conf_file
```

gives:

```
conf_file != NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When I checked my `ps -ef | grep dnsm`

   dnsmasq -x /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -r /var/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service

It is started from /etc/init.d/dnsmasq where it process most of stuff which picks config from /etc/dnsmasq.conf.
So I think it is because of missmatch in init scripts. I see that in my process has most of differant options so please check your dnsmasq init scripts.

may be better if you provide me by trying 
`sudo service dnsmasq restart` and check again if you see same once check in `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq` file for issue. or send the dump if you can.